Recreate exact output from this Linux diff command in a Windows System
I'm losing my mind trying to recreate the output of the following Linux command in a Windows Environment:
diff --old-line-format='%L' --new-line-format='' --unchanged-line-format='' file1 file2 | grep -v '^$'

I can't install anything, not even Notepad++ plugins, since it's a corporate server. All I got to work with is CMD or PowerShell (as far as I can think of)
Closest I've gotten is the following Powershell 'script':
$file1 = Get-Content "file1.txt"
$file2 = Get-Content "file2.txt"

$only_in_file1 = $file1 | Where-Object {
    $_ -notin $file2
}

$only_in_file1

But it fails to show the exact same output I'd get in Linux. Let me explain,
file1:
#AK.70.1.1.5
ServerTokens Prod
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
Header unset "X-Powered-By"
#AK.70.1.1.6
ServerSignature Off
AddServerHeader Off

#ServerTokens Prod
#ServerSignature Off
#AddServerHeader Off

file2:
blah blah blah
durr durr durr
ServerTokens Prod
blah blah blah
durr durr durr
ServerSignature Off
AddServerHeader Off

Expected output (what I'd get in Linux):
#AK.70.1.1.5
ServerTokens Prod
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
Header unset "X-Powered-By"
#AK.70.1.1.6
ServerSignature Off
AddServerHeader Off
#ServerTokens Prod
#ServerSignature Off
#AddServerHeader Off

Actual output (what I get from PowerShell)
#AK.70.1.1.5
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
Header unset "X-Powered-By"
#AK.70.1.1.6
#ServerTokens Prod
#ServerSignature Off
#AddServerHeader Off

You see, although I commented file2 lines in file1, and pasted them on a different place, it stills considers them as if they weren't different.
I really cant Wrap my head around this topic. It's been like 4 hours now. Not kidding.
Any idea is welcome!

I quess, it has to do with different (OS) line terminitions where Get-Content reads multiple (or all) lines as one item. What returns: $file1.Count in either case?

Exactly your guess, both counts return '1': https://imgur.com/a/OfmidE2

If I do split them, it does count the accurate number of lines: https://imgur.com/a/oNBWDCA

Buuuut if I do the 'diff' with the lines, it stills doesn't return the expected output: https://imgur.com/a/6ioy3Ze

@rubénruiz could you put the first 10 lines of both files? and an example of result you want? Maybe can help us :)

Encoding issue? I would check what is actually inside each (specific) line: ... | Format-Hex

@iRon, note that PowerShell is platform-agnostic with respect to newline characters / character sequences. It interchangeably accepts Windows-format CRLF newlines, Unix-format LF-only newlines, and even (now obsolete) CR-only newlines. I also don't think there's an encoding issue: the actual output matches both the PowerShell code and the diff command; it's unclear what the logic behind the expected output is, as it appears not be based on comparing two files at all, but is simply composed of all non-empty lines from the first file.


Your PowerShell code yields the same result as your diff (+ grep) command, because both report only those lines from file1.txt that don't also exist in file2.txt and aren't empty.

In other words: the actual output is the expected result of this logic, and it's unclear why you expect different output:

Your expected output suggests a different logic, which is: retrieve all lines from file1.txt that aren't empty; in other words: the content of file2.txt doesn't matter.

Implementing this logic would simply be the following, i.e. to  retrieve all non-empty lines from file1.txt:
@(Get-Content file1.txt) -ne ''





